# Problema con icono de descargar de Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo el siguiente inconveniente con el navegador de Google Chrome:

Cuando se ejecuta un $.get() dentro de está tengo una función que es `function(data){}` que se ejecuta cuando ya viene la respuesta y dentro de la misma tengo estas lineas de código.

```
var url_with_name = "data:application/pdf;base64," + data;

var html = '<html>' + '<style>html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;}  </style>' + '<body>' + '<p></p>' + '<iframe type="application/pdf" data="'+url_with_name+'" src="' + url_with_name + '"></iframe>' + '</body></html>';

var a = window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data, "Zupfnoter");

a.document.write(html);

a.document.close();
```

Lo que sé, dentro de la función es crear un código html con body y un iframe para poder mostrar con el window.open en una nueva pestaña del navegador el data que sería en formato pdf.

Ahora el momento de probar para descargar la misma el Mozilla Firefox lo realiza con éxito pero en Google Chrome no hace ninguna acción,  ¿A que se debería eso?

Si pueden ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido. Crea un [mcve]. También sería conveniente que siguieras el [tour] y leyeras [ask].

Comment: Posiblemente está relacionado con que document.write se considera una mala práctica, véase [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1595451), y que Google ha decidido intervenir contra document.write, veáse [Intervening against document.write()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write).

Comment: Aunque data de 2015, hay una discusión sobre un tema parecido en el [foro de soporte de Google Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/428NG5agplI) (en inglés). Sé que inicialmente dice `object`, pero más adelante la gente se queja de que ocurre también con `iframe` y parece que podría ser un problema al tener un blob demasiado grande en base64. Entonces,te preguntaría: ¿ves algún mensaje de error/aviso en la consola? ¿Cómo de grande es el blob del pdf? ¿Qué resultado obtienes si quitas el `data` al `iframe`? (sólo necesita el `src`)

Answer (score 0):

Cada navegador está quitando los datos en una ventana nueva por razones de seguridad. (Chrome ha dejado de dar soporte desde la versión +60)

Prueba con un iFrame, jsPPDF o pdfMake

Comment: Las respuestas basadas en enlaces no son bien recibidas en SOes. Si el enlace deja de estar disponible en el futuro tu respuesta será totalmente inutil. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para que el enlace pase de ser esencial a ser un complementario